# Highcharts - no telemetric timeline chart

Tags: highcharts, iot

I want to create a combination between a standard telemetry graph and a graph with non-telemetric values spread over a time axis.

I have a number of examples of graphs for example:
[not telemetric data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xs3z.png)

I thought to use either a bullet graph or in the x range.
But I was able to use these in a way that is synchronized with the normal graph.

ֿI am happy to hear ideas for a similar solution

Comment: No luck with https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types?

Answer (score 0):

To combine, such types of the series, you have to at lest create separate x axes. You can also create separate charts or panes.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime'
  }, {
    type: 'linear'
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'xrange',
    xAxis: 0,
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      y: 1,
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
      x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
      y: 1
    }]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    xAxis: 1
  }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j57q0z9n/